# How to Find & Replace Strings with Incrementing Variables in a Text File Using Awk

Tags: shell, awk, command-line-interface

## Problem

How can I use awk to:

1. Find a string
2. Add an integer to that string
3. Increment the integer
4. Rinse and Repeat until EOF

---

#### Input File

```
Foo Figure
![Figure. Foo](images/foo.png)

Bar Figure
![Figure. "Bar"](images/bar.png)
```

#### Output File

```
Foo Figure
![Figure 1. Foo](images/foo.png)

Bar Figure
![Figure 2. "Bar"](images/bar.png)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'sub(/!\[Figure/,"& "i+1){i++} 1' file
Foo Figure
![Figure 1. Foo](images/foo.png)

Bar Figure
![Figure 2. "Bar"](images/bar.png)
```

Comment: Hey @Ed: is there any way to target the **![Figure** part instead of the **Figure** word only? Your current code targets **Figure** tokens even if the appear outside the markdown code. I've updated the question to take this edge case into account.

Comment: Thank you. 1. Your answer solves my question and came first. Can you expand a bit on what the code snippet does? I'd like to award the answer to you but also help others understand the code better (and myself haha). 2. Can you also update the snippet with your comment above? Just tested and it works as needed.

Comment: Hey Ed, I did check out the online version of EAP but came out even more confused about how the snippet works. The way I see it `/!\[Figure/` is the regex that is doing the targeting. Then the comma `,` is the separator of the arguments. `"& "i+1` is saying "give me the regex match (&) and concatenate the result of `i+1` with it." Then `{i++}` increments the i variable with 1. I don't understand the use of the last 1. I'm pretty sure I've got it all backwards, but I really did try to understand the resource you provided. It's just way above my current skill level.

Comment: According to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script) the `1` at the end of the script is an always true condition that will print every line.

Comment: Question: Is `i+1` initializing the `i` variable on the first run with 0 and then adding 1 to it?

Comment: No, all awk variables are initialized to null-or-zero at startup. `i+1` is just adding 1 to whatever value i has at the time.

Comment: That sounds about right! Thank you for your helpful feedback Ed.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/Figure\./{gsub(/Figure/, "Figure " ++i)}1' File
```

Output:

```
Foo
![Figure 1. Foo](images/foo.png)

Bar
![Figure 2. "Bar"](images/bar.png)
```

Comment: Hey @a-m-d: Same comment as above. Does your code target all **Figure** tokens too? Is it possible to target only **Figure** tokens that appear inside the Markdown code snippets?